# Check the Checkbox to Checked in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a checked Checkbox to be unchecked based on some condition.

Tried writing the below code:

```
$('.chkCouponNumber8').prop('checked', false);
```

But I am unable to achieve .. Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
if($(".chkCouponNumber8").prop('checked') == true){
    //do something
}
else
{
   //do something different
}
```

you can also try:

```
if (!$(".chkCouponNumber8").is(":checked")) {
    // do something if the checkbox is NOT checked
}
else
{
   //do something different
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$('#test').prop('checked', false); // if you are using id as selector



 $('.Classname').prop('checked', false); // if you are using class as selector
```

**make sure your jquery is 1.6+ version**

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkCouponNumber8">
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
if($('.chkCouponNumber8').attr('checked')){
   // do something
}else
{
 // do something
}
```

or

```
var x = document.getElementById("chkCouponNumber8").checked;
if(x== true)
{
// do something
}else
{
// do something
}
```